# Check existing image in NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a picker that saves my image in `NSDocumentDirectory`, here:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < image.count; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [image objectAtIndex:i]);
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
            NSString *documentsDirec = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *savedPath = [documentsDirec stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImages%d.png", i]];
            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[image objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [imageData writeToFile:savedPath atomically:YES];

            NSLog(@"saving at:%@",savedPath);
         }
```

How to determine or implement to check if an existing image/imageName is already there. Then if an images exist it will not add the same image/imageName even if its still picked in the picker.

Comment: @You want to check if an image exists in the Documents directory with the same name. Right?

Comment: Yes, the if it already exists will not save the same one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below code for checking a specific image is already exists in the documents directory:

```
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *imageName = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imageName.jpg"];
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] imageName];
```

In your code you can add it like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < image.count; i++) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [image objectAtIndex:i]);
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(  NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
                NSString *documentsDirec = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *savedPath = [documentsDirec stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImages%d.png", i]];

                BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedPath];

                //Save only if file not exists
                if(!fileExists) {
                ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[image objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
                NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                [imageData writeToFile:savedPath atomically:YES];

                NSLog(@"saving at:%@",savedPath);
               }
             }
```

Comment: Code is wrong. Should be: `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedPath]`

Answer (score 1):

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imageName.jpg"];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
            NSLog(@"file exists at the path");
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"file doesnt exist");
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < image.count; i++) 
     {
        NSLog(@"%@", [image objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
        NSString *documentsDirec = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedPath = [documentsDirec stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myImages%d.png", i]];
        if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:savedPath]) //if not exits then save image
        {
         ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[image objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];
         NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
         [imageData writeToFile:savedPath atomically:YES];
         NSLog(@"saving at:%@",savedPath);
        }
     }
```