# Save signature image in png format in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata

I have drawable text which is used for signature ,
I want this context save in png format with a specific path but I could not do this.I want my draw image save in png format and I can use any where

```
**Code for png format and path**

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_SignatureView.signatureImage);

 NSString *imagePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/imageName.png"];

[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];

_SignatureView is a property and signatureImage is a method 

**code of signature image method**

- (UIImage *)signatureImage
{
    if (!self.hasSignature)
        return nil;


    UIImage *screenshot = [self snapshot];


    return screenshot;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5262262/2168557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
  {
    if (image != nil)
    {
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
       NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
      [NSString stringWithString: @"test.png"] ];
      NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
      [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
      }
  }
```

and to get the image use the following code

```
 - (UIImage*)loadImage
 {
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
   NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
   [NSString stringWithString: @"test.png"] ];
   UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
   return image;
 }
```

Comment: @madhumita Thanks for help.But still i not able to save image

Comment: have you checked wheather your _SignatureView.signatureImage is having image reference?

Comment: :-I checked my iamge show in my next view controller but where it is save ,i don't know.

Comment: I checked in Documents in my mac but there is no image ..Give me solution

Comment: refer this link and print saved image path .After check that in that path.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219202/check-existing-image-in-nsdocumentdirectory

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *docPath=  @"/Users/.../.../";
NSString *filePath=[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PdfFileName.pdf"];

NSMutableData pdfData=[NSMutableData data];
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, bounds, nil);

CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

[YourSignature.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks to All..Who help me...Seriously save lot time..@Abhishek and @Madhu